IIS + Windows Authentication - how to make the MSA account launch a browser (edge/chrome)?
I have an MSA account as my app pool for the website.
My site has a package called Puppeteer that needs to launch a browser inside the server. (Edit: I am using the browser already installed on the server inside C:\Program Files, not the one that Puppeteer wants to install)
In this specific website I am using Windows Authentication to get the company's domain user that's currently using his PC.
The problem is that, what I believe is happening, is that their user is the one trying to launch the browser, but they do not have permission, only the application pool user has (the MSA account).
Because when I switch to Anonymous authentication which then uses the MSA account, it works.
Is there a way to make the MSA account launch the browser even when using Windows Authentication? Or, at least somehow make the Windows user be able to run the browser safely? Maybe create a shortcut in a safe location and give it the right permissions - would that work? Would that be secured?

Does the Puppeteer-controlled browser need to inherit the user's authentication?

Nope I just need to be able to launch the browser. I forgot to mention (but will update now in the post), that I am using the browser already installed on the server, and not the one that comes with Puppeteer because I can't use it

What version of Windows Server? What version of Puppeteer? What version of Edge?

what identity does the Application pool run as? does it have access to all the resources you need?

@FrankThomas when I use Anonymous Authentication, it runs as the MSA account and it's working so I believe it does have everything, but when I switch to the Windows Authentication I see the app is performing requests on behalf of <domain>/<username> which pops up this window on the server: https://i.sstatic.net/jy2XUrjF.png

well, please don't misunderstand, there is only ever 1 application pool identity, the identity that spawns the w3wp.exe process associated with the application pool at runtime. can you confirm that your Application Pool > Advanced Settings > Identity property is set to your MSA user?
Impersonation muddies the waters a bit,  so can you also confirm that in IIS management console > Site > Authentication > ASP Impersonation is disabled? don't focus on the behavior, just confirm the current settings you see in the IIS console for us please.

Oh! I just noticed that the second authentication option in the list which I never looked at is the ASP.NET Impersonation, but it's always been disabled (I'm using a PHP app). So yes - Impersonation is disabled and always has been, and the domain/msaUser is indeed acting as the current application pool identity.

Is your MSA user configured to act as a user on the systems in question? when your app fails to do what you want it to, check the security logs for "failure" entries around that time. if there are any, they are likely related to your MSA users access, but you should be able to tell if which user account is being denied from there. if you don't see any security log failure entries related to your app, then the issue is probably not the access issue you are troubleshooting.

@FrankThomas there is indeed an error in the Event Viewer (under System) when I try to run the script: The application-specific permission settings do not grant Local Activation permission for the COM Server application with CLSID {xxx} and APPID {yyy} to the user <mydomain/myMSA_account> SID (some long number) from address LocalHost (Using LRPC) running in the application container Unavailable SID (Unavailable). This security permission can be modified using the Component Services administrative tool., though it's under System and not Security. Could that be related?

@FrankThomas update: When I test with a simple HTML string it works! I used: Browsershot::html('<h1>Test</h1>)  and there's no error. But when I pass the full rendered HTML string it prompt this authorization window. Something inside the full HTML string blocks it

So on your CLSID error, the first thing to note is that it is occuring within the context of the application pool user (your MSA user) so this issue is not related to impersonation. your second test with the abreviated HTML, indicates that you are not having a problem invoking the browser in question. those together indicate that the issue is internal to the app's behavior and its environment configuration. Your best bet is to probably review the application installation guide, and support options. that said, my experience with .net on IIS, has been that CLSID errors are usually a red herring.

@FrankThomas, I found the problem! grawity's comment below gave me a hint, he asked what website I am trying to visit to create the HTML and I said that I am just passing HTML and not visiting a webite. Then I realized that the HTML string contains a link to one of the CSS files, but as full URL, including the https://. Thus I believe the corporate security detects that as trying to access an external URL (which many of them are blocked here). When I changed the full URL to relative URL, it worked!

From what I understand, the issue is that accepting Windows Authentication in IIS also by default performs impersonation on behalf of that user – making the app run with that user's privileges – and switching privileges via impersonation (as opposed to a full 'logon') is likely incompatible with the various security hardening and sandboxing features that modern browsers (Chrome in particular?) want to use.
So the first thing I'd try, if possible, is to disable impersonation – e.g. maybe:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65266848/force-iis-not-to-impersonate-user

If that doesn't work... split the project into two sites – a frontend that accepts Windows Authentication, and which talks over an internal API (using some other form of authentication, e.g. static API key) to a backend that uses Puppeteer. At some point in the future, you might end up needing to do so anyway.

you can also configure impersonation in the web.config in case you need to version control it. you also have a few options with impersonation, such as explicitly setting the impersonated user (though this has the caveat of requiring a password in the config file).  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/developer/webapps/aspnet/development/implement-impersonation . While I would not generally recommend impersonation for most sites, it is a useful tool when working with integrated authentication.

Thank you! I will try the first option first i.e. disabling impersonation - is it something I can do in the IIS GUI?

so its been some years since i bothered with Windows Integrated Auth for webapps, but my recommendation is that you enable impersonation, but then tell it to use an explicit account like <identity impersonate="true" userName="accountname" password="password" />.  we used to have to do this when our database connection strings used integrated security, and the app pool ran as a domain user with database access, but the individual users did not have DB access rights. it forced the app to use an account with access to the data.

@FrankThomas thank you. Where do I put that line exactly? In the web.config? also, userName refer to the MSA account right? Do you know if instead of editing the web.config file itself, I can do it via the GUI? Because when I use the GUI it places the XML tags exactly where they need to be so I know there aren't errors on my side. Also I am using PHP and not ASP so I hope it would still work

@FrankThomas: How does that differ from not enabling impersonation at all, and having the application run as the specified user from the beginning? My rough understanding is that it's not some user's lack of permissions that breaks the puppeteed browser, but the use of an impersonated token in general that is incompatible with what the browser tries to do.

@grawity, I agree with you, that there must be something additional going on, unless op enabled implicit-impersonation explicitly, and in that case, disabling it should do the trick, but Impersonation is not default-on when windows auth is enabled (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/134ec8tc(v=vs.100)) so enabling explicit impersonation may be the best bet. from what Op is saying something is still missing from the equation, so at least in this configuration, we are being explicit about our desired state. worth trying once anyway.

@Stackerito, the UI options for impersonation are in the "Authentication" widget in the center pane of the IIS management console when you select the site or app. Note that impersonation can only use a windows user available on the server (domain or locally defined user). I don't know what the "MSA" account you are reffering to is, so can't say for certain. it should be a user who has access to whatever resources you need the site to have access to.

MSA (Managed Service Account) is a domain account for which the OS (or even the DC for gMSA) automatically manages the password, similar to the way machine accounts are handled but for use by services.

The problem is that when I use Windows Authentication, then whenever a user tries to use the part of the website that launches Puppeteer (and Microsoft Edge), it prompts this Authorization window on the server: https://i.sstatic.net/jy2XUrjF.png, and it doesn't do it when I switch to Anonymous. It does seem to be permission issue, but it looks like it happens because Microsoft Edge is installed on C:\Program Files and the domain users that IIS is using via Windows Authentication don't have permissions to this location (it's just my guess, though not sure)

What could cause this window to pop up though? I am still not sure. Is it permissions issue?

It sounds like you're trying to Puppeteer a webapp that itself wants to receive Windows Authentication (SPNEGO)?

I'm not sure because I am using Puppeteer as part of a Laravel package that uses Puppeteer behind the scenes, called Browsershot. Also what's confusing to me is that the window that pop says Authorization, and not Authentication. And I don't see anything related to authorization on IIS. So I have no idea as to whether it's a Server-wide permission issue, or something in the IIS configuration only. All I know is that when Anonymous Authentication is enabled, it works, but when I disable it and enable Windows Authentication, then this authorization window pops up

HTTP uses the terms interchangeably. The HTTP header delivering authentication data (both Basic and SPNEGO) from client to server is also called Authorization:, while it is requested by the server sending an WWW-Authenticate: header.

Oh got it, thank you. So maybe when I use Windows Authentication, then when Browsershot tries to run Puppeteer (and launch the Edge browser in C:\Program Files), it does not have enough permissions to run it from this path? For example mydomain\myuser can't access C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\? (But then why does Anonymous users do have - or - when I use Anonymous, it is run as the MSA account which is OK?)

Not sure – I suspect that it can access that, but then Edge fails to set up its security sandboxing... What kind of website are you trying to 'visit' using Browsershot, though? Internal app or normal external website?

@grawity I am passing HTML to browsershot: Browsershot::html($someHtml) and no Browsershot::url(), so I am not visiting any website

@grawity update: I just checked: When I pass a simple html string: Browsershot::html('<h1>Test</h1>) it works! So it must be something in the html string itself

@grawity thank you! Your hint helped me! The problem was that the HTML string included a full URL to one of the CSS files and our corporate has strict security so I believe it was detected as trying to access some forbidden external URL. When I changed the link to the CSS file to use a relative path: <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/mystyle.css"> it worked!

I assume it's not exactly forbidden, but rather it goes to a server which requires the same SPNEGO/Windows Authentication to access (and that would in theory be possible to have on the server, but only with "unconstrained delegation" enabled).
